# Demonstrate that solution of differential equation is bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, estimation, cauchy-problem

Let $b(t) \in C^1([0,+\infty))$. I have to find a formula for the solution of this Cauchy's problem:

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x''(t)+x(t)&=b(t) \\
x(0)&=x_0\\
x'(0)&=x_1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
I have solved this part of the question and the formula is:
$$x(t) = x_0\cos(t)+x_1\sin(t) -\cos(t)\int_0^tb(s)\sin(s)\,ds+\sin(t)\int_0^tb(s)\cos(s)\,ds.$$
Then the problem asks to demonstrate that if $b(t)$ is bounded and monotone also $x(t)$ is bounded. It also asks to find a counterexample if $b(t)$ is bounded but not monotone. I can solve the second part by picking for example $b(t) = \cos(t)$ but I'm not able to demonstrate the first fact. I have tried to estimate $|x(t)|$ but the only inequality I come up with is $|x(t)| \leq |x_0|+|x_1|+2Mt$ where $M:=\max_{[0,+\infty)}|b(t)|.$

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $x$ will in general oscillate. How does one understand "monotone" in that context?

Comment: By "limitated", do you mean "bounded"?

Comment: @Keister Yes i mean bounded

Comment: @Lutzl Sorry i mistiped. I had to demonstrate that x is bounded! I'll edit the question

Comment: If $(b_k)$ is monotonically increasing and bounded, then $b_*=\lim_kb_k$ exists and $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k(b_k-b_*)$ which converges by the Leibniz rule, making the sequence of partial sums bounded. You will need to use something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $b\in C^1$ and monotonous, the sign of $b'$ is constant.
Partial integration gives 
$$
\int_0^t\sin(t-s)b(s)ds=[\cos(t-s)b(s)]_0^t+\int_0^t\cos(t-s)b'(s)ds
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^t\sin(t-s)b(s)ds\right|&\le |b(t)-b(0)\cos(t)|+\int_0^t|b'(s)|ds
\\
&\le|b(0)|+|b(t)|+|b(t)-b(0)|\le 2b^*=2\sup_{s\ge0}|b(s)|.
\end{align}

In some way this is an integral version of the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) for series.